# Updating sharepoint lists via database?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to find a more efficient way to update multiple fields on a sharepoint site without having to dropdown -> right click, or having to manually load the website in such a way that we can edit the field from the web page itself.

I don't and will not have access to sharepoint designer, so I was hoping there is some database out there I could have access to, where I could UPDATE the fields at one time instead of manually editing each field(extremely slow).

Forgive me if I'm wrong, but I believe all fields on a sharepoint site are held in a database? If I have admin access to the sharepoint, will I have access to any of these databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not have access to the backend database.

Even if you did, directly querying the underlying SQL Server database is frowned upon... it's only supported in a few edge cases (mainly for reporting) and any modifications run the risk of putting your database into an unsupported state.

Instead, SharePoint exposes an object model that can be used to programmatically access SharePoint objects (such as sites, lists, columns, and list items).

The SharePoint object model is exposed through the following APIs:

1. [Managed server-side object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint(v=office.14).aspx) (which must be executed from one of the SharePoint web front-end servers)
2. [Managed .NET client-side object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537855(v=office.14).aspx)
3. [SOAP-based web services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee705814(v=office.14).aspx)
4. [REST Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx)
5. [JavaScript client object model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185006(v=office.14).aspx)

With your level of access, you can use any of the four latter options (just no server-side code), but they each require varying levels of programming expertise.