# SQL Query to copy SharePoint list to SQL table

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint

I am new to coding and am still in learning phase.

I have got a task to create a scheduler which would copy data from a SharePoint List into a SQL table.

I need to write a SQL query to copy SharePoint List into a SQL Table. I have searched and found many ways like SSIS. But I have been specifically asked to do this using SQL Query.

Any insight on how to start is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you certain that it's necessary to do this task solely via SQL query?  You won't ordinarily be able to access the SharePoint database with a direct SQL query (and even if you can, its schema is not going to look normal), but you can instead use one of the available [APIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39126486/updating-sharepoint-lists-via-database/39130649#39130649).